# Torrent client with IP filtering and IP filter auto-updating

Tags: linux, bittorrent

I'm looking for a torrent client for **linux** where I can have IP filtering with auto-updating.
I know about qBittorrent, it allows you to choose a IP filter (.dat, .p2p, .p2b) and use it, but it does not allow auto-updating.

Does anyone know any alternative?

Thanks

Comment: What if you just use your system's firewall to block these problematic IPs ? Make a cron job that updates an IPSet (better than individual rules for large amounts of IPs) every X minutes and forget it; and finally you can use any torrent client you want.